# Update .json file from google drive in android app

Tags: android, json, google-drive-api

I developed android app that uses the data from .Json file from row folder?

Now I need that this .`json` file access from drive and automatically update in app when i update .`json` file in google drive?

Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Possible. You can listen for events on a specific Google Drive file using the API. Check out the documentation about that on this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/events).

Implement periodic checks or set a background service on your app and then do whatever updates you are doing in your application.